# Create a LINQ for SQL query

Tags: sql, linq

I'm learning Linq and using MVC. I have written a SQL query which I need to convert to a LINQ query.

```
select TokenID,TokenAsset,packet from TokenTable where id = 6 and packet = ''
and TokenID not in (select TokenID from TokenTable where id=6 and packet <> '')
group by TokenID,TokenAsset,Packet
```

I kindly ask help to convert the above query to a LINQ query. I know that the SQL query isn't efficient. It would better if you can help me to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly your SQL query can just be

```
select distinct TokenID, TokenAsset, packet 
from TokenTable 
where id = 6 and packet = ''
```

the `group by` is not that useful since there are no aggregated columns. All selected columns are in the `group by` clause. Use `distinct` to achieve the same.

the secondary AND condition for tokenid is also redundant. It is exclusive to the first condition and hence doesn't change the result.

use this LINQ query:

```
var results = dbcontext.TokenTables
              .Where(t => t.id == 6 && t.Packet == "")
              .Select(t => new { t.TokenId, t.TokenAsset, t.Packet }).Distinct();
```

project only columns you need for performant calls by avoiding extra data transfer.

Comment: Suggesting to use `distinct` instead of `group by` is good. However, suggesting that the second condition is redundant without knowing the data structure can be incorrect. You don't know what values (or `NULL`s) the TokenID field has. Notice that the "id" and "TokenID" seem to be two different fields.

Comment: @Racil, couldn't correlate your comment with the query.. first part of query is all tokenIds which have id = 6 and **packet =""**, which means the tokenids for records with **packet != ""** will implicitly  be excluded because of the AND conditions.. please let me know if i am missing something.. glad to understand and edit my understanding

Comment: Yes, the first condition will eliminate all the `packet <> ''`. However, the second condition may eliminate even more. For instance, you are assuming that "TokenID" is the key for the "TokenTable", but what if it is not? and what is "id"? If duplicate values for "TokenID" exist for some "id"s: let's say (id=6,ToketID=2,Packet=''),(id=6,TokenID=2,Packet='p'), the first condition will eliminate the second row, but then the second condition will eliminate the first row as well.

Comment: Racil latest comment is right. Will the Linq work as per the comments?

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
var result = Tokens.Where(x=>x.Id==6 && 
                          x.Packet=="" &&
                          !Tokens.Exists(y=>y.TokenID==x.TokenID && 
                                            y.Id==6 && 
                                            y.Packet!="")
                   )
                   .GroupBy(x=>x.ID)
                   .ThenGroupBy(x=>x.TokenAsset)
                   .ThenGroupBy(x=>x.Packet);
```

**Note** I suppose that collection `Tokens` holds all the tokens you have.

Comment: What happened to the `not in` part?

Comment: I don't think we need the not. If you look at sql query you will get what I mean. we need all tokens that have id==6 and their packet is empty. Actually, I think we want only these records. Otherwise the provided query doesn't make sense.

Comment: Are you saying that removing it will still give the same results? Notice that the "id" and "TokenID" seem to be two different fields.

Comment: Ah I see what you mean, thanks I am on correcting right now. Thanks !